# How can I confirm PHP MongoDB connection is properly recognizing replica sets?

Tags: php, mongodb

Using the [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php) from the manual:

```
$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://sf2.example.com,ny1.example.com", array("replicaSet" => "myReplSet"));
```

When I check $mongo, it says it is indeed connected. I thought I could then call $mongo->isMaster() to get replica set details, but that doesn't work. Is that not a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isMaster` isn't a PHP function (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php for a list of functions available in the `Mongo` class).  You can do:

```
$result = $mongo->myDb->command(array("isMaster" => 1));
```

This runs the isMaster command on the myDb database (it doesn't matter what db you run it on).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was misled by the answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559474/list-of-php-mongo-questions-what-does-construct-return-when-replicaset-is-true